# GitLab integration with Jaeger in Azure kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, jaeger

I have installed Gitlab in AKS cluster, and I also installed Jaeger. Both the applications are up and running.
I want to integrate GitLab with jaeger.
I searched for any documentation on how to do in AKS , but didnt find any.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

GitLab Helm charts support tracing, and you can configure it with:

```
global:
  tracing:
    connection:
      string: 'opentracing://jaeger?http_endpoint=http%3A%2F%2Fjaeger.example.com%3A14268%2Fapi%2Ftraces&sampler=const&sampler_param=1'
    urlTemplate: 'http://jaeger-ui.example.com/search?service={{ service }}&tags=%7B"correlation_id"%3A"{{ correlation_id }}"%7D'
```

For more details refer :https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/charts/globals.html#tracing